# List of company IDs for manufacturer specific data in BLE advertising packets

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Where can I find the list of registered company IDs which are set right after the AD type field in an AD Structure in a BLE advertising packet when the AD type is 0xFF (Manufacturer Specific Data)?

To be concrete, for example, how can I find the information telling that Apple's company ID is 0x4C00? (In an iBeacon packet, AD Type 0xFF is followed by 0x4C and 0x00.)

Comment: Reading the list pointed to by davidgyoung, I found the company ID of Apple is 0x004C, not 0x4C00. It seems that the two bytes should be regarded as represented in the little endian order.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The list of two-byte Bluetooth company identifiers, sometimes called the CIC, can be found here:

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers/

The page also has a link to request a new company identifier.

Comment: Shame there's no "individual / small scale" option. 0xFFFF may be suitable but it's a little unclear if it is a special value in a technical sense. If I use 0xFFFF, the Nordic Master Control Panel says the vendor is "Reserved".

Comment: According to the Bluetooth specification, the value 0xFFFF is reserved for testing purposes *only* and cannot be used for shipping commercial products. It is intended for companies, maybe still not members of the Bluetooth SIG (Special Interest Group) who are in the process of receiving its own Company Identifier Code.

Comment: The field is only 16 bits, I believe there must be more than 65536 companies in the world that are using/will use Bluetooth LE. So is this 16 bit ID really significant?

Comment: @zerox: isn't this ID for the manufacturer?  Do you believe there are more than 65536 companies manufacturing bluetooth products who need their own ID?

Comment: Just look at the list.  As of July 22, 2017 there were 1,326 registered company identifiers.

Comment: @davidgyoung The link is now a 404 :(

Comment: For historical reference: 2135 registered companies as of 2020 january 05.

Comment: New link: https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf

Comment: **Holy Five Hells of Standardization Failure.** What was Bluetooth SIG cogitating when they confined manufacturer IDs to 16 bits? The world's gonna easily blow through that barrier sometime in the 2020's. What's the grand forward-compatible plan then? O_o